# Space between text elements (title and content) in text editor

Tags: text

I am trying to minimize the space between the **title and the content in my text editor**.

In fact, I have created an H5 and an H6, but when I use it, a large space puts between the two elements (picture). Would you know how I could **minimize the space between those elements?** In order to have the **content right beneath the title?**

*I have tried minimizing the line height of my H5, but this does not work, in fact, when I put large titles, the letters overlap.*

[image]
[image]

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: This can't be controlled via the editor. It's the styling from your theme. You'll need to use CSS to adjust the margins. I can't say exactly what CSS since I don't know what the current CSS is.

Comment: It'd specifically be the `editor.css` if this is in the backend.  You want to use this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/  (Assuming you have either a child theme or a custom theme, you won't be able to add this to a third party theme.  I guess you could also make a plugin just to add your `editor.css`, but that seems like overkill.)